# GLSL Shaders in 3DSMax

Tags: graphics, 3d, glsl, shader, 3dsmax

So I've looked around, and since I have found no information on the subject, I assume 3DSMax does not support GLSL shaders? Is this correct?

I am using 3DSMax 2010 and 2011, and am sick of writing two versions of the same sets of shaders - one for my application and one for 3DSMax. So much gets lost on the crappy workflow :(

Does anyone have any information on how to render with GLSL shaders in 3DSMax 2010 or 2011?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 2010 and higher the directX material also supports CGFX shaders as well as HLSL. Both formats might require slight tweaking to support 3ds max's parameter system as well as a game engine.

In 2011 and 2012, Autodesk added support for **[metaSL](http://www.mentalimages.com/products/metasl.html)**, a format from NVIDIA (formerly mental images).  MetaSL shaders can export into CG, HLSL, GLSL, and also MentalRay Shaders.

- The metaSL export or compliation engine is available via the ***mental mill integrators edition*** (expensive). This is for game engine writers that want users to author additional shaders. eg. UnReal, Unity3d etc.
- Content (ie. metasl, glsl,hlsl, etc,) can be created via ***mental mill standard edition*** which is free with a license of 3ds max 2011 and higher. (500$ without 3ds max)
- There is also a way to author metaSL shaders directly in the 3ds max 2012 schematic material editor removing the need for *mental mill* as a standalone product.

Answer (score 3):

it supports DirectX shaders and metasl shaders.

You can code your own shaders (maxscript, c++ plugin, metasl) to fill the gap.
But you will not be able to see a unsupported material in the viewport.

Answer (score 2):

Vray 2.0 supports rendering of GLSL shaders on 3dsmax 2011 and above, though it is by no means a free rendering engine.

Vray:
http://chaosgroup.com/en/2/vray.html

GLSL Documentation:
http://www.spot3d.com/vray/help/200R1/vrayglsltex.htm